# How to use Google Search in VB.NET Application?

Tags: vb.net, linq, search

I wanted to develop a VB.NET application that uses google search and get the search results such as the urls etc.

My initial plan was to use Google's ATOM Custom Search API and use LINQ to parse the data I need to get. But I found out that by using Custom Search API, it only searches the site/s that is defined when creating the custom search engine.

In order to achieve my goal for this application, I need to get the search results that like when searching in google search and not for a specific site. I also need the results in a format that I can parse such as the result using Google's ATOM Custom Search API.

Here are my questions:

1) Can I use Google Custom Search to get the search results such as google search shows? Or is it just or a custom site?

2) Is there a way that I could request Google Search and retrieve the results back in a format I can work with?

If anyone could point me to the right track that would be very much appreciated. Suggestions are also very welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find helpful code and further information at http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

The Custom Search API is made for Javascript, but you could convert the code to VB.Net